# Why Image is getting swap after delete from array in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to delete image

For delete I am using code like this

In DidFinishLoading

```
imageArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int i=0; i<idarray.count; i++) {
    [imageArray addObject:[UIImage new]];
}
```

In CellForrowAtIndexPath

```
cell.btnRemove.tag=indexPath.row;
 [cell.btnRemove addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRemoveClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Button Click

```
 -(void)btnRemoveClick:(UIButton *)sender
    {
    UIAlertView *Alertview =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Are You Sure you want to delete Image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"NO" otherButtonTitles:@"YES", nil];
            [Alertview show];
    }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
            [imageArray removeObjectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
            [imageArray addObject:[UIImage new]];
            [Audittable reloadData];
}
```

But When I delete image image get swap as in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhoWk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KntGh.png)

CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *STI=@"STI";
        AuditNextTableViewCell *cell = (AuditNextTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AuditNextTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        cell.audittitlelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[idarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.nameidlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[CheckpointNameIDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.passlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Passarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.faillbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Failarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.warninglbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Warningarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.nalbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NAarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.popuplbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[Popuparray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
        // cell.remarklbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[PFWNAArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        DataModel *model2 = [AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.lblAuditTextBox.text=model2.AuditTextBoxString;

        //cell.lblAuditTextBox.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AuditTextBoxarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        cell.AuditCountlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld)", (long)indexPath.row +1];

        cell.CaptureImage.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // tag add on buttons
    cell.passbtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.failbtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.wipbtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.nabtn.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.Photobtn.tag=indexPath.row;
    cell.btnRemove.tag=indexPath.row;

    //method add on buttons
    [cell.passbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnP:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.failbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnF:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.wipbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnW:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.nabtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnNA:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.Photobtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnphotoClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnRemove addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRemoveClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"AuditPost"];
    self.devices = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

    ComplareArray=[devices valueForKey:@"checkpointid"];

    countcellbtn.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)ComplareArray.count];


    if (![arrIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [arrIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }

    if (![PassarrIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath])
    {
        [PassarrIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }


    //background color change on button
    DataModel *model = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"P"])
    {
        cell.passbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"F"])
    {
        cell.failbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    }
    else if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"W"])
    {
        cell.wipbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else if([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"NA"])
    {
        cell.nabtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else if ([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"PA"])
    {
        cell.passbtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else if ([model.strSelected isEqualToString:@"NAA"])
    {
        cell.nabtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.passbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.failbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.wipbtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        cell.nabtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    }


    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:0.5f];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you show your cellForRowAtIndexPath code

Comment: @Priyal Please check the update question

Comment: You are removing an image object and then adding an empty image object. The empty image object is "appended" not "replaced". You should fetch that image object from the index and replace it. I hope you are clear otherwise, let me know.

Comment: Plz check this code as Priyal says... [imageArray removeObjectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath];
            [imageArray addObject:[UIImage new]];

Comment: @Priyal Not getting I replaced like this but it remove both image             [imageArray replaceObjectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath withObject:[UIImage new]];

Comment: @DSDharma But it removing 2 image from array.

Comment: In this method 'didDismissWithButtonIndex' you should check condition to remove image based on YES or NO by user selection.Seems image will be deleted by any selection.

Comment: In your code identified deleting images from array single time only. Put a debug pointer and check line by line it will be helpful

Comment: @DSDharma I just change code like this             [imageArray replaceObjectAtIndex:CurrentIndexPath withObject:[UIImage new]]; and its done.